# How to set font color of UISegmentedControl for iPhone ios 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

How to set font color of UISegmentedControl for iPhone ios 4.3?

For ios 5.0 i use

```
UISegmentedControl *button = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] 
initWithItems:[NSArray >arrayWithObjects:itemTitle, nil]] autorelease];

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontColor forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[button setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];


button.momentary = YES;
button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
button.tintColor = tintColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be such a bad idea to use a custom project, especially because OS 4.x doesn't have the deep UIKit customization possible in 5.x.  Here's an excellent one in Github which actually solves both of your requirements for setting both the size and color of the UIControl: [Here](https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl)

EDIT: it looks like the project automatically chooses the font color to match the selected color.  At least it's a start.